# Dojo code not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, dojo, google-earth

I am attempting to reuse some open source code that exists at http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fdemos%2Fdom-tree.
I copied the code, including the javascript file included at this same location, and when i run it, it runs great in ie 8.0.  Will not run in 9.0 for some reason.  But my real problem is that it will not run in FireFox.  What gets me, is that there is a demo of this code online, and it runs just fine in Firefox.  I cannot see a difference at all in it.  This code will take me a long ways towards completing a project i am working on, and so any help would be very much appreciated!  The Demo is at http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/dom-tree/index.html.

Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to see the demo in a local folder in your computer, it won't work. Most of the time Dojo code and respective demos requires the page to be loaded from a server. I don't know exactly why this happens (because javascript runs locally right?), but it is so.

If you want to check, test and modify the code locally, do it using a local server setup, such as [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (in case you've never used it before, it's really easy to setup, especially in Windows).

To run Dojo code in IE9 make sure you use the [latest 1.6.1 version](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/); previous versions won't work very well, or at all.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I do have it hosted on a server however, and i have the latest Dojo code running.  (I am not positive i am referencing it properly though).  Here is the address to the site, and if you look at it in the ie browser, and Firefox, you will see the problem i am having.

Comment: The problem (large aerial image not showing) seems related with the Google Earth plug-in, not with Dojo. The Dojo parts load fine (the layout containers, buttons, checkbox tree, etc). In you example your running Dojo 1.3.2, not 1.6.1, that's maybe why the dijits don't show properly in IE 9.0.

Comment: Works in IE8 and Chrome (except the large aerial image is not showing). Doesn't show anything in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: I failed to mention that you have to have the Google Earth Plugin installed in order for the large image to appear. How can you tell that it is 1.3.2?  I do not doubt you, i just don't see that.  I downloaded 1.6.1, but that doesn't mean i did not load it correctly.  I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I looked into the source code, and it seems to be loading 1.3.2; check this line: google.load('dojo', '1.2.3'); and your code loading 1.6.1 is commented, so I don't think it's working: <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

Comment: That helps a lot!  Thank you!  Now, it does not work in IE8, but, i am getting another error.  Ultimately, you answered my question though, i just need to keep filtering through these errors as they come up, until they are all resolved.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Here is my current error.         Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SearchToolbar 1.2; GTB7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDR; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; MS-RTC EA 2; BRI/2; MS STORE DMC2.6.3411.2)
Timestamp: Thu, 9 Jun 2011 14:11:43 UTC


Message: Module: 'dojo' with version '1.6.1' not found!
Line: 32
Char: 847
Code: 0
URI: http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA5a4NhilcmrdMQ5e3o22QWRQWrGbhbxAguaJ-a4SLWYiya7Z2NRTDfQBdxmHdf5ydkZYLZTi

Comment: It seems that google.load cannot load 1.6.1. Try removing google.load('dojo', '1.6.1') and load Dojo 1.6.1 the normal way, but without the comments you had previously: <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"; type="text/javascript"></script> . I must tell you, this is not an easy accomplishment, because you're dealing with a mix of old (possibly incompatible) dojo code and other proprietary google stuff... good luck!

Comment: I will see what i can do.  Once more, thank you for your help!